# Using Charts with Realm in Objective-C

Tags: ios, cocoapods, realm, ios-charts

My project is mostly written in Objective-C and I'm using Realm in it.
I want to add Charts library with realm support but I get an error when trying to add it using cocoapods.

The Podfile looks like that (with some other libraries)

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MY_PROJECT' do
pod 'Realm'
pod 'Charts/Realm'
end
```

and the error I'm getting is this:

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Realm` required by `Podfile`
- `Realm` required by `Podfile`
- `Realm` required by `Podfile`
- `Realm (= 2.0.0)` required by `Podfile.lock`
- `Realm (= 0.97.0)` required by `RealmSwift (0.97.0)`
```

Since my project is mixed, I can't use RealmSwift directly.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A problem is not mixing Realm and RealmSwift. You seems install Realm without Charts first, then add Charts to the Podfile then `pod install`, right? So the `Podfile.lock` (a file pinning library to specific version) pinned Realm to `2.0.0` but Charts requires older version of RealmSwift (RealmSwift depends on Realm implicitely). That is the cause of the error.

To resolve that, you can execute `pod update` or just delete `pod 'Realm'` from the Podfile. Either way remove Realm 2.0 then install Realm and RealmSwift 1.1.0 (1.1.0 is Chart's required).

You cannot use higher version of Realm because Charts requres 1.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, there is no way to use a mixed Realm and RealmSwift application. From the [docs](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/):

> If you’re looking to use Realm purely from Swift, you should consider
>   using Realm Swift instead. The Realm Objective‑C and Realm Swift APIs
>   are not interoperable and using them together is not supported.

My recommendation to you, anyway, is using Realm Cocoa (Objective-C) from Swift so there's no major problem with your application using the database. Don't mix in your Podfile both of the dependencies. Use only Realm and not RealmSwift.

Comment: I'm not trying to use RealmSwift directly but it is probably required by the charts. I've updated the question to include the Podfile.

Comment: That's correct. Check out the Podspec for `Charts` 2.3.0. There is a dependency requiring RealmSwift: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/Charts/2.3.0/Charts.podspec.json This is the source of the error. What I said previously is happening here: The Realm (Objective-C) and RealmSwift libraries are not interoperable.

Comment: I see. Is there anything I can do about it? or should I just wait for an update?

Comment: Maybe you should file an Issue on Github for the Charts library and describe the problem. I can't tell you what to do because it depends totally on the roadmap and plans for the development of Charts.